# Windows Server 2008 SP2 and Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.2?

Tags: windows-server-2008, .net-framework

Based on Microsoft knowledge base, the operating system Windows Server 2008 SP2 has stopped at .NET framework 4.6. Due to a software's dependencies on .NET 4.6.2, the program can not be installed on the server, as it does not have the .Net 4.6.2.

I would like to ask you if by any mean is there a way to make the package Microsoft .Net Framework 4.6.2 able to be installed and as a result the program of interest.

I have done some research through the Registry entries, but so far, I could not make that work in that Server.

Any ideas and/or if I should just leave it as it is?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Server 2008 is completely End of Life. You really shouldn't still be using it at all.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to ask you if by any mean is there a way to make the package Microsoft .Net Framework 4.6.2 able to be installed and as a result the program of interest.

`.NET Framework 4.6.2` cannot be installed on `Windows Server 2008 R2`.

> Any ideas and/or if I should just leave it as it is?

Due to the fact .NET Framework 4.6.2 cannot be installed on the operating system you are currently using, there isn't really a solution to your problem, `.NET Framework 4.6.2` is actually supported by `Windows Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1`

Source: [.NET Framework system requirements](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/get-started/system-requirements)